# Altering a script to write the results to a file

Tags: vbscript

I have the following script which is gathering all of the information I need but I was wondering how I alter it to print all of the results that are displayed in the windows to a list of some sort? I would like to manipulate this data in excel.

```
Dim arrHeaders(35)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:directory")

For i = 0 to 34
  arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
Next

For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
  For i = 0 to 34
    Wscript.Echo i & vbtab & arrHeaders(i) _
      & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the detail information in another array and echo each record as a comma-separated line:

```
Dim arrData(35)
...

WScript.Echo Join(arrHeaders, ",")

For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
  For i = 0 to 34
    arrData(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
  Next
  WScript.Echo Join(arrData, ",")
Next
```

That way you can redirect the output to a CSV file by running the script with `cscript.exe` like this:

```
cscript //NoLogo "C:\path\to\your.vbs" > "C:\path\to\your.csv"
```

The CSV file can then be opened with Excel.

Another option is to use the `FileSystemObject` to write the output file from within the script:

```
Dim arrData(35)
...

Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.csv", 2, True)

f.WriteLine Join(arrHeaders, ",")

For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
  For i = 0 to 34
    arrData(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
  Next
  f.WriteLine Join(arrData, ",")
Next

f.Close
```

Comment: Hiya, thank you so much for this, it makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately I'm not so savvy when it comes to these scripts. How would I combine the two to work properly without the windows popping up and to create the csv file?

Comment: @Donald You don't combine them. You use one or the other. Or did you mean how to integrate either of my suggestions with your existing code? Consider that your homework.

Comment: Yes, I meant integrating the code together to work. I appreciate your help and will try and figure it out, though I'm really busy at work and don't have the time for self-teaching right now, so any further help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to modify the script to send the output to a file. Just open a console, navigate to script location and run the script, redirecting the output from console to a file

```
myvbscript.vbs > myoutputfile.txt
```

See:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Hiya, that sounds perfect, but what do I type in cmd to actually run the script? I know how to navigate to a directory. And how do I prevent it from opening windows to display the information, I want it go straight to the file?

Comment: Once you are in the directory containing the script, type the script file name in the console to run it. See my previous example and replace myvbscript.vbs with the real script file name and myoutputfile.txt with the desired name of the output file to generate.

Comment: I tried that but it's still showing the dialogue boxes and doesn't print anything to the text file. I have 180 files to read through this script and having to click 34 OK's per file is a little time consuming. :(

Comment: The default interpreter is `wscript.exe`, which will display `WScript.Echo` messages as dialog boxes, not echo them to `StdOut`. You need to run the script with `cscript.exe` or make `cscript.exe` the default interpreter for redirection to work.